# Center form label and text in row

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with a label and form which I want to center in the row, but encountering difficulties to do that. The label wont move to center next to the input field without moving the field down. This is the code:

```
<div class="row"> 
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-6 control-label pull right">Password: </label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" name="Password" class='form-control'  />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Did you try `text-align: right;`?

Answer (score 0):

```
width:100%;text-align:center;display:inline-block;
```

In the style attribute of your label.

Answer (score 0):

You messed up your `div`s and put your `col-md-6` on the wrong element.

Try:

```
<div class="row"> 
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label pull-right">Password: </label>
         </div> 
         <div class="col-md-6">
            <input name="Password" class="form-control" type="text">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Ex: http://www.bootply.com/133293